# Windows Server 2008 IP block using built-in firewall issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, windows-firewall

So here's the situation:

I'd like to block one or more IP addresses using native firewall that comes with Windows Server 2008. I opened it, chosen to create a new rule under inbound rules. I choose as follows: custom rule, all programs, any protocol, put remote IP address, set to block it, give a name and save.

When I look at the list, or edit it, I can see that the protocol field has automatically changed to HOPOPT. Every time I set it to 'Any', it turns back to HOPOPT after save, again and again. Can anyone tell me why?

I just want to deny all possible services for some users that I host on my machine (including websites on IIS7), but I can't. Please help.

Best Regards,

Ventus

Answer (score 0):

Almost sounds like you don't have permissions to edit the firewall rules.  Are you applying this to "domain","public" and "Home" networks?  You need to identify where windows thinks this traffic is coming from and block it based on its source.

I can't comment on why the interface refuses to let you save.  I do know that the list can get quite long when adding rules and I often wonder where my rule went and it ends up at the bottom of the list off the screen.